# Extract a substring up to 1000th comma

Tags: java

I have a string (comma seperated)

For example:

```
a,bgf,sad,asd,rfw,fd,se,sdf,sdf,...
```

What I need is to extract a substring up to the 1000th comma.

How to achieve this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way of doing this would be to use indexof(int ch, int fromIndex) intead of using split(String regex, int limit) or split(String regex) especially if the given string is long.
This could be done something like this

```
[pseudocode]

asciiCodeForComma = 0x2c
nextIndex=0
loop 1000 times
 nextIndex= csv.indexof(asciiCodeForComma , nextIndex)

requiredSubString = csv.subString(0, nextIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String csv = "some,large,string";
String[] parts = csv.split(",");
String thousandthElement = null; // the default value if there are less than 1000
if (parts.length > 999)
    thousandthElement = parts[999];
```

Comment: it's a homework, so I guess a direct solution shouldn't be given here

Comment: @LeleDumbo, if its `[homework]` the student would be expected to demonstrate they can write it themselves rather than use a built in method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) with comma as separator, then loop nextToken() 1000 times.

Answer (score 0):

I think he is asking for all 1000 element.. This should solve your problem. Understand and then copy-paste as this is ur homework  :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String samplecsv = "a,bgf,sad,asd,rfw,fd,se,sdf,sdf,";
         String[] splitedText = samplecsv.split(",");
         StringBuffer newtext = new StringBuffer();
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
             newtext.append(splitedText[i]);
        }
         System.out.println(newtext);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this problem what you need to do is understand how to extract a string from a delimiter separated input stream.  Then executing this for the case for N strings is trivial.  The pseudocode for doing this for the individual record is below:

```
function parse(inputValue, delimiter)  
{  
   return inputValue.split(delimiter)  
}
```

Now to do that for the case where there are N inputValues is equally as trivial.

```
function parse(inputValues, delimiter)  
{
  foreach inputValue in inputValues  
     returnValue.append(parse(inputValue,delimiter)  
  return returnValue    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually built in functionality to do this by putting a second argument into split.  If what you're really looking for is the whole string before the 1000th comma, you can still use this function but you will have to concatenate the first section of the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String sample = "s,a,m,p,l,e";
    String[] splitSample = sample.split(",",1000);
    if (splitSample.length == 1000)
        System.out.println(splitSample[1000]);
    else
        System.out.println("Your error string");
}
```